# API or technical documentation for including a new service in Microsoft Office's "insert online pictures" pane

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ms-office

Microsoft Office 2013 and higher includes an "online pictures" option in the "insert" ribbon. By default it includes options for Bing image search and sharepoint. There is a link that implies there is some way to add additional services via a Microsoft account, but this did not work when I tried it.

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way I can leverage this existing tool to allow our users to search and place images from our PHP/MySQL-based ResourceSpace digital asset management system. I would assume there would be some sort of API and process for including an additional web service in the Office UI, but I haven't had much luck finding it. Wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction on finding some technical details about this feature. Or is it just another Microsoft walled garden?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is still a bit of a walled garden (the integration is non-trivial). This however is an excellent scenario for an Office Web Add-in. There are commercial examples of exactly this scenario in the Office Store today ([Shutterstock Images](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380169&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&homprd=Office&sourcecorrid=850ef9a2-4a07-4f50-8a41-756d2ebe87c7&homappcat=Editor%2527s%2BPicks&homapppos=2&homchv=1&appredirect=false), [PicHit](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104178141&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&homprd=Office&sourcecorrid=850ef9a2-4a07-4f50-8a41-756d2ebe87c7&homappcat=Best%2BApps%2Bof%2Bthe%2BYear&homapppos=1&homchv=0&appredirect=false)).

From an API perspective, you'd want to leverage the [Document.setSelectedDataAsync](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.setselecteddataasync) method. There are some subtle differences between the types of content that can be inserted (referred to as the [CoercionType](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/coerciontype-enumeration)) but I suspect it fits what you're looking for. In PowerPoint, Excel and Word you can insert any Base64 image (`Office.CoercionType.Image`). With Word you can insert raw HTML so a standard `<img>` tag can be used with a URL to the source image ((`Office.CoercionType.Html`).